# How do I get the latest timestamp value per day?

Tags: sql, sqlite

In a sqlite DB, I have two fields.  A value field, and a timestamp field.  I want to get the value for the last timestamp for each day.  For example, with records like this:

```
Value  |  Timestamp
1         2017-05-26 14:38:48
2         2017-05-26 15:38:48
3         2017-05-26 16:38:48
4         2017-05-29 14:38:48
5         2017-05-29 15:38:48
6         2017-05-29 16:38:48
```

I'd like to return the two max values per day.

```
Value  |  Timestamp
3         2017-05-26 16:38:48
6         2017-05-29 16:38:48
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `date` function which returns the date part of datetime column and get the latest time per day.

```
select * from tbl
where timestampcol in (select max(timestampcol) 
                       from tbl 
                       group by date(timestampcol)
                      )
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I knew there was an elegant solution, but I just couldn't find it.  I didn't know about the date function.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite 3.7.11 or later [does the right thing](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg) without a subquery:

```
SELECT Value, max(Timestamp)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY date(Timestamp);
```